# How to make walls that can be moved by velocity code but can't be moved by anything else?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am creating a game where you play as a ball and the walls move around you in different directions. My problem is that when it hits the wall it adds force to the wall, moving it in directions I don't want. I have tried freezing the position or making them kinematic but if I do that, they won't be able to be moved by velocity code. Is there any way to create walls that can be moved by physics code?

Comment: Do you need walls to be rigidbodies? And why?

Comment: Add to wall just box colliders, dont need to have rigidbody on walls if they wont be affected by gravity and other bodies.

Comment: @ToniK I need rigid bodies because I want to move the walls with velocity and if I use transform to move the walls it will collide strangely with the ball.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "strange collision" when you use transform? If you are willing to settle for "collisions barely move the wall" you can just increase the mass of the wall to something big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. I was wrong that kinematic rigid bodies couldn't be affected by velocities. They can and I used that to solve my problem